# Why must I triple click this link?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I am designing a website and in the navigation I have 2 links that have dropdown menus ("About" and "Services"). When you hover your mouse over the links, the dropdown appears, then when you click on the link, the dropdown menu disappears, then if you click it again the dropdown reappears. So basically, in order to go to that page you have to triple click the link. Does anyone know what I can do to change this so it brings you to the page after just one click?

This is what the navigation looks like in my HTML code:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <span><a href="about.html">About ▼</a></span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="background.html">Background</a></li>
                <li><a href="why.html">Why Choose Us?</a></li>
                <li><a href="management.html">Management</a></li>
                <li><a href="university.html">Financial University</a></li>
                <li><a href="media.html">Media ►</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="television.html">Television Appearances</a></li>
                        <li><a href="articles.html">Articles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="books.html">Books</a></li>
                        <li><a href="financialsafari.html">Financial Safari</a></li>
                        <li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span><a href="services.html">Services ▼</a></span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="retire.html">Retirement Planning</a></li>
                <li><a href="annuities.html">Annuities</a></li>
                <li><a href="estate.html">Estate Planning</a></li>
                <li><a href="insurance.html">Insurance</a></li>
                <li><a href="business.html">Business Consulting</a></li>
                <li><a href="taxes.html">Tax Planning</a></li>
                <li><a href="invest.html">Investment Management</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
#nav
{ position: absolute; right: 2em; line-height: 5.5em; }

#nav > ul > li
{ float: left; padding: 0 0.8em 0 0.8em; }

#nav > ul > li > a, 
#nav > ul > li > span
{ color: #fff; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 800; font-size: 0.95em; letter-spacing: 0.075em; padding: 0.5em 0.8em 0.5em 0.8em; border-radius: 6px; outline: 0; }

#nav a
{ color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; }

#nav a:visited
{ color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; }

#nav > ul > li.active > a,
#nav > ul > li.current_page_item > a,
#nav > ul > li.active > span,
#nav > ul > li.current_page_item > span
{ background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15); box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.025), 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.025); }

#nav > ul > li:last-child
{ padding-right: 0; }

#nav > ul > li > ul
{ display: none; margin-top: -2px; }
```

---

EDIT: I found out the dropdown menu is controlled by a piece of jQuery called dropotron. Here is the CSS regarding dropotron:

```
.dropotron
{   
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38,38,38,0.95), rgba(59,59,59,0.95));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38,38,38,0.95), rgba(59,59,59,0.95));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38,38,38,0.95), rgba(59,59,59,0.95));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38,38,38,0.95), rgba(59,59,59,0.95));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(38,38,38,0.95), rgba(59,59,59,0.95));
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.075), inset 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), 0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,1);
    padding: 1.5em;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    min-width: 15em;

}

    .dropotron-level-0
    {
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
        margin-top: -2px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.075), 0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }

    .dropotron a,
    .dropotron span
    {
        color: #aaa;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 800;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        letter-spacing: 0.075em;
        outline: 0;
    }

    .dropotron li:hover > a,
    .dropotron li:hover > span
    {
        color: #fff;
    }
```

Here is the jQuery file for Dropotron

```
(function(jQuery) {

jQuery.fn.disableSelection_dropotron = function() { return jQuery(this).css('user-select', 'none').css('-khtml-user-select', 'none').css('-moz-user-select', 'none').css('-o-user-select', 'none').css('-webkit-user-select', 'none'); }

jQuery.fn.dropotron = function(options) {
    var settings = jQuery.extend({
        selectorParent:     jQuery(this)
    }, options);
    return jQuery.dropotron(settings);
}

jQuery.dropotron = function(options) {

    // Settings
        var settings = jQuery.extend({
            selectorParent:         null,               // The parent jQuery object
            baseZIndex:             1000,               // Base Z-Index
            menuClass:              'dropotron',        // Menu class (assigned to every UL)
            expandMode:             'hover',            // Expansion mode ("hover" or "click")
            hoverDelay:             150,                // Hover delay (in ms)
            hideDelay:              250,                // Hide delay (in ms; 0 disables)
            openerClass:            'opener',           // Opener class
            openerActiveClass:      'active',           // Active opener class
            submenuClassPrefix:     'dropotron-level-', // Submenu class prefix
            mode:                   'slide',            // Menu mode ("instant", "fade", "slide", "zoom")
            speed:                  'fast',             // Menu speed ("fast", "slow", or ms)
            easing:                 'swing',            // Easing mode ("swing", ???)
            alignment:              'left',             // Alignment ("left", "center", "right")
            offsetX:                0,                  // Submenu offset X
            offsetY:                0,                  // Submenu offset Y
            globalOffsetY:          0,                  // Global offset Y
            IEOffsetX:              0,                  // IE Offset X
            IEOffsetY:              0,                  // IE Offset Y
            noOpenerFade:           false,              // If true, when in "fade" mode the top-level opener will not fade with the menu
            detach:                 true                // Detach second level menus (to prevent parent styling from bleeding through)
        }, options);

    // Variables
        var _top = settings.selectorParent, _menus = _top.find('ul');
        var _window = jQuery('html');
        var isLocked = false, hoverTimeoutId = null, hideTimeoutId = null;
        var _isTouch = !!('ontouchstart' in window), _eventType = 'click';

    // Main
        _top
            .bind('doCollapseAll', function() {
                _menus
                    .trigger('doCollapse');
            });

        _menus.each(function() {
            var menu = jQuery(this), opener = menu.parent();

            if (settings.hideDelay > 0)
                menu.add(opener)
                    .mouseleave(function(e) {
                        window.clearTimeout(hideTimeoutId);
                        hideTimeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
                            menu.trigger('doCollapse');
                        }, settings.hideDelay);
                    });

            menu
                .disableSelection_dropotron()
                .hide()
                .addClass(settings.menuClass)
                .css('position', 'absolute')
                .mouseenter(function(e) {
                    window.clearTimeout(hideTimeoutId);
                })
                .bind('doExpand', function() {

                    if (menu.is(':visible'))
                        return false;

                    window.clearTimeout(hideTimeoutId);

                    _menus.each(function() {
                        var t = jQuery(this);
                        if (!jQuery.contains(t.get(0), opener.get(0)))
                            t.trigger('doCollapse');
                    });

                    var x, c, left, top, isTL = (menu.css('z-index') == settings.baseZIndex), oo = opener.offset(), op = opener.position(), opp = opener.parent().position(), ow = opener.outerWidth(), mw = menu.outerWidth();

                    if (isTL)
                    {
                        if (!settings.detach)
                            x = op;
                        else
                            x = oo;

                        top = x.top + opener.outerHeight() + settings.globalOffsetY;
                        c = settings.alignment;

                        menu
                            .removeClass('left')
                            .removeClass('right')
                            .removeClass('center');

                        switch (settings.alignment)
                        {
                            case 'right':
                                left = x.left - mw + ow;

                                if (left < 0)
                                {
                                    left = x.left;
                                    c = 'left';
                                }

                                break;

                            case 'center':
                                left = x.left - Math.floor((mw - ow) / 2);

                                if (left < 0)
                                {
                                    left = x.left;
                                    c = 'left';
                                }
                                else if (left + mw > _window.width())
                                {
                                    left = x.left - mw + ow;
                                    c = 'right';
                                }

                                break;

                            case 'left':
                            default:
                                left = x.left;

                                if (left + mw > _window.width())
                                {
                                    left = x.left - mw + ow;
                                    c = 'right';
                                }

                                break;
                        }

                        menu.addClass(c);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Non-static position fix
                            if (opener.css('position') == 'relative'
                            ||  opener.css('position') == 'absolute')
                            {
                                top = settings.offsetY;
                                left = (-1 * op.left);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                top = op.top + settings.offsetY;
                                left = 0;
                            }

                        switch (settings.alignment)
                        {
                            case 'right':
                                left += (-1 * opener.parent().outerWidth()) + settings.offsetX;

                                break;

                            case 'center':
                            case 'left':
                            default:
                                left += opener.parent().outerWidth() + settings.offsetX;

                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./) && RegExp.$1 < 8)
                    {
                        left += settings.IEOffsetX;
                        top += settings.IEOffsetY;
                    }

                    menu
                        .css('left', left + 'px')
                        .css('top', top + 'px');

                    menu.css('opacity', '0.01').show();

                    // Kludge!
                        var tmp = false;

                        // Non-static position fix
                            if (opener.css('position') == 'relative'
                            ||  opener.css('position') == 'absolute')
                                left = (-1 * op.left);
                            else
                                left = 0;

                        if (menu.offset().left < 0)
                        {
                            left += opener.parent().outerWidth() - settings.offsetX;
                            tmp = true;
                        }
                        else if (menu.offset().left + mw > _window.width())
                        {
                            left += (-1 * opener.parent().outerWidth()) - settings.offsetX;
                            tmp = true;
                        }

                        if (tmp)
                            menu.css('left', left + 'px');

                        menu.hide().css('opacity', '1');

                    switch (settings.mode)
                    {
                        case 'zoom':

                            isLocked = true;

                            opener.addClass(settings.openerActiveClass);
                            menu.animate({
                                width: 'toggle',
                                height: 'toggle'
                            }, settings.speed, settings.easing, function() {
                                isLocked = false;
                            });

                            break;

                        case 'slide':

                            isLocked = true;

                            opener.addClass(settings.openerActiveClass);
                            menu.animate({ height: 'toggle' }, settings.speed, settings.easing, function() {
                                isLocked = false;
                            });

                            break;

                        case 'fade':

                            isLocked = true;

                            if (isTL && !settings.noOpenerFade)
                            {
                                var tmp;

                                if (settings.speed == 'slow')
                                    tmp = 80;
                                else if (settings.speed == 'fast')
                                    tmp = 40;
                                else
                                    tmp = Math.floor(settings.speed / 2);

                                opener.fadeTo(tmp, 0.01, function() {
                                    opener.addClass(settings.openerActiveClass);
                                    opener.fadeTo(settings.speed, 1);
                                    menu.fadeIn(settings.speed, function() {
                                        isLocked = false;
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                opener.addClass(settings.openerActiveClass);
                                opener.fadeTo(settings.speed, 1);
                                menu.fadeIn(settings.speed, function() {
                                    isLocked = false;
                                });
                            }

                            break;

                        case 'instant':
                        default:

                            opener.addClass(settings.openerActiveClass);
                            menu.show();

                            break;
                    }

                    return false;
                })
                .bind('doCollapse', function() {

                    if (!menu.is(':visible'))
                        return false;

                    menu.hide();
                    opener.removeClass(settings.openerActiveClass);
                    menu.find('.' + settings.openerActiveClass).removeClass(settings.openerActiveClass);
                    menu.find('ul').hide();

                    return false;

                })
                .bind('doToggle', function(e) {

                    if (menu.is(':visible'))
                        menu.trigger('doCollapse');
                    else
                        menu.trigger('doExpand');

                    return false;

                });

            opener
                .disableSelection_dropotron()
                .addClass('opener')
                .css('cursor', 'pointer')
                .bind(_eventType, function(e) {

                    if (isLocked)
                        return;

                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    menu.trigger('doToggle');

                });

            if (settings.expandMode == 'hover')
                opener.hover(function(e) {
                        if (isLocked)   
                            return;
                        hoverTimeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
                            menu.trigger('doExpand');
                        }, settings.hoverDelay);
                    },
                    function (e) {
                        window.clearTimeout(hoverTimeoutId);
                    }
                );
        });

        _menus.find('a')
            .css('display', 'block')
            .click(function(e) {

                if (isLocked)
                    return;

                _top.trigger('doCollapseAll');

                e.stopPropagation();

                if (jQuery(this).attr('href').length < 1)
                    e.preventDefault();

            });

        _top.find('li')
            .css('white-space', 'nowrap')
            .each(function() {
                var t = jQuery(this), a = t.children('a'), ul = t.children('ul');

                a.click(function(e) {
                    if (jQuery(this).attr('href').length < 1)
                        e.preventDefault();
                    else
                        e.stopPropagation();
                });

                if (a.length > 0 && ul.length == 0)
                    t.click(function(e) {

                        if (isLocked)
                            return;

                        _top.trigger('doCollapseAll');

                        e.stopPropagation();

                    });
            });

        _top.children('li').each(function() {

            var opener = jQuery(this), menu = opener.children('ul');

            if (menu.length > 0)
            {
                if (settings.detach)
                    menu
                        .detach()
                        .appendTo('body');

                for(var z = settings.baseZIndex, i = 1, y = menu; y.length > 0; i++)
                {
                    y.css('z-index', z++);

                    if (settings.submenuClassPrefix)
                        y.addClass(settings.submenuClassPrefix + (z - 1 - settings.baseZIndex));

                    y = y.find('> li > ul');
                }
            }

        });

        _window
            .click(function() {
                if (!isLocked)
                    _top.trigger('doCollapseAll');
            })
            .keypress(function(e) {
                if (!isLocked
                &&  e.keyCode == 27) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    _top.trigger('doCollapseAll');
                }
            });
};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: please make a fiddle .. there is no all the relevant css what about the css for show the submenu?

Comment: Agreed, the way it is now we can only click on the "Services" and "About" with no sub menus

Comment: Try changing your UX from click to hover till you reach the last element or <li> in navigation.

Comment: Sorry, I did forget the most important part of the code. Good catch Danko.

Comment: @warnakey - why don't you use http://jsfiddle.net/ to paste your code?

Comment: This was my attempt at a fiddle but yeah it does not look like its working..  http://jsfiddle.net/m6c2A/  If you can manage to get your code into a fiddle.  Or share a link to your live site then I might be able to help..

Comment: @Trevor, http://retirementautopilot.com/capitalfinancial/ --> This is a link to a copy of it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @warnakey I think I misunderstood the problem in the first place.  I think I understand what you want now.  Let me take one more crack at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a guess try adding this jQuery to your page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#nav .opener').click(function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).find('span a').attr('href');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: I added that in the <head> of my HTML, but it still has the same result. You can check the source code and see if I applied it correctly, but I think I have.

Comment: @warnakey check my updated answer..  Also inside the `#nav .opener` click function add an `alert('test');` or something just to see if the code is being run when the drop down is clicked.

Comment: Done. Take a look again. The alert works, but for some reason it isn't taking me to the pages likes it should.

Comment: What about doing something like: window.open("www.youraddress.com","_self"), in place of the alert?

Comment: @warnakey Yeah I think your on the right track.  Try my update.

Comment: I want to have your baby. hahahahaha. Thank you SO much!!! In all seriousness, you are brilliant and it would have taken me days to figure that out.